# How to create relative increase drawn in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I saw in an excel sheet this formatting:
[image]

How to create this?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select your data then `Home > Conditional Formatting > Data Bars`, possibly > More Rules..., adjust to suit